# for loop where criteria is last data record in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame (data). I would like to run a for loop through it. I want to label the output as either 0 or 1 based on whether the next instance (p) in the data frame (data) is equal to (==) or not equal to (!=) the previous record. At the moment, I just get a list of '1's' but having checked print(p) the for loop is looping. Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

```
data <- data.frame(movementObjects$Movement)

for (p in seq(1, nrow(data)-1)){
if (p == p-1) 
changes <- 0
else {
if (p != p-1)
changes <- 1
print(changes)
}
}
```

Sorry, I'm new to R. Here is an example of one of the datsets but this is a string I have numerical ones too. All i want is a data frame output labelled according to whether the previous 'movement' is equal to or not equal to the last

```
 movementObjects.Movement
1                       left
2                    forward
3                    forward
4                 non-moving
5                 non-moving
6                 non-moving
7                       left
8                 non-moving
9                      right
10                   forward
11                non-moving
12                non-moving
13                non-moving
```

I guess like this:

```
1    1
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
```

Comment: You don't need a `for` loop. Just show an example of your data and your desired output

Comment: how can a number be equal to itself minus 1 ? (maybe you rather wanted to write `data[p, ]` and `data[p-1, ]` ?). Also, why do you define a new data.frame that consists of one column of the data.frame you already have ?

Comment: @CathG I'm guessing OP tries to use it as an index

Comment: Please follow DavidArenburg's advice and post (editing your question) a sample of your data.frame and what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I guess you want `v1 <- movementObjects$Movement; c(0,+(v1[-1]!=v1[-length(v1)]))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, it is (changing your data.frame name to `df` and the column names to `movement` for clarity):

```
`+`(tail(df$movement, -1) != head(df$movement, -1))
#[1] 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

***Explanation:***
`tail` permits to consider only the (n-1) last elements (n being the total number of elements), while `head` permits to consider the (n-1) first element. Then you compare those 2 vectors to find the differences and, finally, you use `+` to convert the logical result into numeric.

***Note:*** As mentioned by @ColonelBeauvel, you can index `df` with `-1` to avoid the use of tail:

```
`+`(df$movement[-1] != head(df$movement, -1))
```

**EDIT,** *if you really want to know how to modify your script to make your `for` loop work:*

```
changes <- c()
for (p in 2:nrow(df)){
   if (df[p, 1] == df[p-1, 1]) changes <- c(changes, 0) else changes <- c(changes, 1)
}
print(changes)
# [1] 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

Comment: more simply `c(NA, head(df[,1],-1)==df[,1][-1])+0L`

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel actually, FALSE is suppose to be 1 and TRUE 0 but ! will be better than abs(...-1) !

Comment: @akrun, I don't know if the result needs to be of same length as the original dataset but yes, you're right if it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you all very much. That piece of code @CathG is really simple and works a treat. Just for reference, would it be possible to use a for loop? I have many data columns that require similar executions. Many thanks.

Comment: @HoffiCoffi, you can use `apply` on your columns if you need to do the exact same thing on each column (or a for loop, looping on the column index). It is always possible to do a for loop but why would you, if you don't need to ? (I'm not sure if your question is how to use a for loop to do this for one column or to do this for several ones)

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I have a model that I want to apply to a dataset and I'm trying to get to grips with applying loops to data based eventually on the criteria of the model. Very helpful thank you.

Comment: An example for loop on the example data here would be helpful. Maybe elaborate on what I was originally trying to do?