# Loop will not execute in R

Tags: r

I have a loop I want to execute that depends on the output of the previous loop in the code. This is the code;

```
holder <- list()
if (i < historyLength) movement <- movementType(relAngle, angleThreshold)

else if (i > historyLength-1) {
  # Array to store speeds
  speedHistory <- array(historyLength)
  n = historyLength-1
  # get the speeds from the previous n (hisoryLength) "Movements" 
  for (j in seq(1, length(historyLength))){
    speedHistory [n] = R[i-j, 6]
    n-1
  }

  if (!bayesFilter(speedHistory, minSpeed, GPS_accy)) movement <- "non-moving" 
  else if(bayesFilter(speedHistory, minSpeed, GPS_accy)) movement <- movementType(relAngle, angleThreshold)

}


holder [[i]] <- (movement)
for (t in seq(1, length(holder))){
  if (t == t-1) 
    changes <- 0 
  else if (t != t-1) 
    changes <- 1
}
```

You cannot see the beginning of loop but it results in a column of data called 'movements.'

I have attempted to temporarily store the 'movements' in the object 'holder.' What i want then is for the bottom for loop to go through 'holder' and label changes as either 0 or 1 in another column. Basically if the next 'movement' is not equal to the previous record the change as 0 and so forth. I think the problem is with the object 'holder' perhaps?

Currently I'm getting it to loop but it's only printing out a column of '1's.'

Any help much appreciated! Thanks.

Currently get the following output:

```
Movement        Changes
left               1 
right              1
forward            1 
non-moving         1
non-moving         1
```

Think the problem lies in the list where movements are stored? Sorry, if I knew where the problem was I'd be more specific. Really new to this!

I end up with a data frame with column headers "Distance" "Speed" "Heading" "Movement" and "Changes." It's looping fine but for some reason Changes reults in a column of 1's as above. Is there an obvious mistake below?:

```
holder[[i]] <- (movement)
 for (t in seq(1, length(holder))){
  if (t == t-1) 
    changes <- 0 
  else if (t != t-1) 
    changes <- 1
```

I have also tried this, but then it doesn't loop at all.

```
holder[[i]] <- (movement)
 for (t in seq(1, length(holder))){
  if (holder[t] == holder[t-1]) 
    changes <- 0 
  else if (holder[t] != holder[t-1]) 
    changes <- 1
```

I'm currently getting this error: Error in holder[[t - 1]] : attempt to select less than one element

for the following code:

```
holder <- list(movement)
 for (t in length(holder)){
  if (holder[[t]] == holder[[t-1]]) 
    changes <- 0
  else changes <- 1
```

Comment: wasn't your problem solved [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903733/for-loop-where-criteria-is-last-data-record-in-r) ?

Comment: Hi. yes the initial problem was solved. I have tried and tried within the main body of the code though and it just prints a series of 1's for some reason? I think it may be because of the list I'm storing the previous data in but can't be sure.

Comment: could you share a snippet of your data? we do not know the structure of the objects you are dealing with. also what particular libraries you might be using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is too long for a comment so I'm putting this as answer (actually it might answer your problem):

As I already mentioned in a comment to your previous question, you should have a look at what is `seq(1, length(holder))` and so what you are doing when you put `if (t == t-1)` : you are doing something like "if 1==0" which cannot be TRUE.

You need to go with "the second version" of your loop (or, actually, without a loop...), which compares the right things, except that `holder` is a `list` so you need to either define it as a vector or use double brackets (`holder[[t]]`).

You don't need another `if` after `else` (what you  are actually "saying" to R is "if `A` is true then do something, else, if 'opposite `A`' is true then do something else" but, necessarily, if `A` is not TRUE, then 'opposite `A`' is...
So something like:

```
for (t in seq(length(holder))){
  if (holder[[t]] == holder[[t-1]]) changes <- 0 else  changes <- 1
}
```

Please consider spending some time on the answer from your previous question to understand why your solution didn't work and why the answer provided did. (This includes reading documentations for the different functions and also take a look at the values your variable can take, e.g. running the loop, one "turn" at a time).

Comment: Thanks for that. For some reason I now get: Error in holder[[t]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @HoffiCoffi, probably because at some point `t` is not in the range (1, length(holder)). Check the value of `t` when you get this message error, it will probably give you the reason